# rotate action android not only landscape or portrait

Tags: android

I'm new on android and i want learn more about how can use phone function . I try make a ball when rotate phone change color , example **rotate 45 grade** become red , but not only orientation landscape and portrait , someone can help me ? or with 1 tutorial ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use orientation, but motion sensors.
You can find about this there http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html